# Адаптивная таблица для ПК и телефона

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, таблицы

Таблица под мобильную версию, чтобы на компе отображалась в 4 колонки, а на мобиле 2 колонки.

Нужно добавить клас к словам "Женщине", "Маме".......

[Скрин на мобиле](https://nimb.ws/a7cXVt)

```
<div class="block">
<div class="col"><a href="https://syte.ru/?p=2230"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-2220" src="https://syte.ru/wp-content/uploads/adled3izl60_2-150x150.jpg" alt="Женщина" width="150" height="150" /></a>
<a href="https://syte.ru/?p=2230">Женщине</a></div>
<div class="col"><a href="https://syte.ru/?p=2330"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-2218" src="https://syte.ru/wp-content/uploads/c3d88a54cf9_2-150x150.jpg" alt="мама" width="150" height="150" /></a>
<a href="https://syte.ru/?p=2330">Маме</a></div>
<div class="col"><a href="https://syte.ru/?p=2336"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-2228" src="https://syte.ru/wp-content/uploads/badd3izl30_2-150x150.jpg" alt="Жена" width="150" height="150" /></a>
<a href="https://syte.ru/?p=2336">Жене</a></div>
<div class="col"><a href="https://syte.ru/?p=2424"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-2225" src="https://syte.ru/wp-content/uploads/395dako_2-150x150.jpg" alt="Дочь" width="150" height="150" /></a>
<a href="https://syte.ru/?p=2424">Дочери</a></div>
<div class="col"><a href="https://syte.ru/?p=2625"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-2233" src="https://syte.ru/wp-content/uploads/uded3hj61f_2-150x150.jpg" alt="Сестре" width="150" height="150" /></a>
<a href="https://syte.ru/?p=2625">Сестре</a></div>
<div class="col"><a href="https://syte.ru/?p=2732"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-2234" src="https://syte.ru/wp-content/uploads/gjrwmhki_2-150x150.jpg" alt="Любимая" width="150" height="150" /></a>
<a href="https://syte.ru/?p=2732">Любимой</a></div>
<div class="col"><a href="https://syte.ru/?p=2903"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-2235" src="https://syte.ru/wp-content/uploads/hgtcci1fg_2-150x150.jpg" alt="Бабушка" width="150" height="150" /></a>
<a href="https://syte.ru/?p=2903">Бабушке</a></div>
<div class="col"><a href="https://syte.ru/?p=3373"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-2236" src="https://syte.ru/wp-content/uploads/erynisth_2-150x150.jpg" alt="тетя" width="150" height="150" /></a>
<a href="https://syte.ru/?p=3373">Тете</a></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: используйте медиазапросы

Comment: вставьте код, который у вас не получается адаптировать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
} 

.col {
  width: 25%;
}


@media(max-width:400px)
{
.col{
  width: 50%;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="col">123</div>
  <div class="col">123</div>
  <div class="col">123</div>
  <div class="col">123</div>
<div>
```

Comment: @ВиталийШебаницБлагодарю что откликнулись. Если вас не затруднит просьба "дошлифовать" код. Я сделал правку вопроса с кодом и с скрином как должно выглядеть все на самом деле.